# Running other processes while recording audio

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, audio

I'm writing an application as part of a project that involves recording audio from an embedded microphone.  The application uses a GUI to let the user control when the application starts recording.  My problem is that when the recording starts I lose the ability to use any other part of my GUI.  So far I've been reduced to using threads and having them sleep until say 30 seconds then they stop the recording.  I'm looking to let the user press one button to start recording, and one to stop.  Does anyone have any suggestions on a strategy I should use?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on which GUI technology that you are using but in general the GUI runs on its own separate thread and should never actually run heavy actions because it will lead to a GUI freeze.

Multithreading is the obvious answer here. In pseudocode (depends too much on technology and is rather verbose to type it fully):

```
startButton.onClick {
    new Thread(myRunnable).start();
}
stopButton.onClick {
    myRunnable.stop();
}
```